# Tastypie: include computed field from a related model?

Tags: python, django, tastypie

I've looked through Tastypie's documentation and searched for a while, but can't seem to find an answer to this.

Let's say that we've got two models: `Student` and `Assignment`, with a one-to-many relationship between them. The `Assignment` model includes an `assignment_date` field. Basically, I'd like to build an API using Tastypie that returns `Student` objects **sorted by most recent assignment date**. Whether the sorting is done on the server or in the client side doesn't matter - but wherever the sorting is done, the `assignment_date` is needed to sort by.

Idea #1: just return the assignments along with the students.

```
class StudentResource(ModelResource):
    assignments = fields.OneToManyField(
        AssignmentResource, 'assignments', full=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Student.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'student'
```

Unfortunately, each student may have tens or hundreds of assignments, so this is bloated and unnecessary.

Idea #2: augment the data during the dehydrate cycle.

```
class StudentResource(ModelResource):    
    class Meta:
        queryset = models.Student.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'student'

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.data['last_assignment_date'] = (models.Assignment
            .filter(student=bundle.data['id'])
            .order_by('assignment_date')[0].assignment_date)
```

This is not ideal, since it'll be performing a separate database roundtrip for each student record. It's also not very declarative, nor elegant.

So, is there a good way to get this kind of functionality with Tastypie? Or is there a better way to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a ModelResource by a field name. Check out this part of the documentation http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#ordering

You could also set this ordering by default in the Model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering